# Get Posts data from facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all the **posts** of my facebook account wall in android. I have got session but when I execute the below query then it gives an error.

```
new Request(fbSession,"/me?fields=posts",null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
                 {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        ShowToast(response.toString());
                    }
                 }).executeAsync();
```

Error:

> Active Access Token must be used to query information about the current user

Although I have an active session variable, which can retrieve my basic information

Comment: you also have to pass your token to get data..

Comment: @Prag's how to pass token there ??? can you please tell me that

Comment: Look at this : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook,it's provide easy way to integrate Facebook with your project

Comment: @Haresh this method have been depricated i were using that, but it would't not work once we logged in

Answer (score 0):

1) It means you don't have an access token or  access token does not match the current logged in user.

2) You have an expired or non-working access token (perhaps left over from the last time you used the app?). You could try clearing that out and re-authenticating.

3)

```
 if (state.isOpened())
 {
       new Request(fbSession,"/me?fields=posts",null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
             {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                  ShowToast(response.toString());
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
  }
```

for more info see below link:-

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: My session variable is correct and i can get basic information like email,id, education with it, but it give an error if i put "posts" in the fields